# How Wix use simplified chinese not traditional chinese

Tags: wix

I've tried to change language to `chinese`
[image: image-20200813103214059]
[image: image-20200813103244357]
but system use `traditional chinese not simplified chinese` like below photo

Wix Chat :
`我們會盡快回復` should be translated to `我们会尽快回复`
`技術支援` should be translated to `技术支援`

[image]

Sorting :
`名稱` should be translated to `名称`

[image: image-20200813103040678]

Product Quick View :
`快速瀏覽` should be translated to `快速浏览`
[image]

Product :
`首頁` should be translated to `首页`
[image]

Comment: Yeah, having the same issue as well. Currently wix only offers traditional :(. However, some wix components are blocked in mainland China, so it doesn't matter too much I guess.

Comment: Same issue here. Wix says the translation is done by Google, but it shows translation into Traditional Chinese, only used in Hong Kong and Taiwan. When I do a right click on the English part of my site, and choose translate in to Simplified Chinese, Google provides the correct translation, most of the time. So there is a problem with the Google Translate integration, I think.
So back to manual translation!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wix available language list: https://support.wix.com/en/article/languages-available-in-wix-multilingual, I guess that they says chinese means traditional chinese not simplified chinese.

Comment: thanks , it's a confusing design , because no one use simplified chinese in china mainland

Comment: @Wei: I'm pretty sure everyone in Mainland China uses Simplified Chinese (see the flag icon). The users of Traditional Chinese are predominantly found in Taiwan. Not sure about Hong Kong.

Comment: @MSalters yes,so it's confusing design,I've reported to wix